# Exception while trying to get data from json string

Tags: java, android, gson

I am creating an android app that displays weather data it's getting in json format from an online API. For that I'm using the GSON libary.

I have the following JSON string, which i got from a map object:

```
String weather = jsonJavaRootObject.get("weather").toString();
```

It contains the following value:

```
{id=800, main=Clear, description=clear sky, icon=01n}
```

But when i try to create another Map object with that string i get an exception.

```
Map weatherMap = new Gson().fromJson(weather, Map.class);
```

The exception logcat report:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at
>   line 1 column 43

I'm confused, because I have tried the same with another json string as the following and it worked just fine:

```
{temp=277.15, pressure=1021, humidity=80, temp_min=277.15, temp_max=277.15}
```

Comment: please check with keeping string in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings have to be between double quotes

```
{id=800, main="Clear", description="clear sky", icon=01n}
```

Comment: Thanks, pushed in some quotation marks with a method. Code is disgusting now but it works.

Comment: Just keep in mind that strings in a JSON object have to be between quotes. You may find another way to do that :)
Anyway, glad that it helped